# DOM Ready in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I am surprised that there are very few articles online addressing this issue. I am trying to create the famous "DOM ready" event for IE 9 and 10 in vanilla JavaScript and here's my code (stripped down to it's core):

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
      document.getElementById("toggled").innerHTML = "ready";
      alert("Stop!");
  }
}
```

Now the problem I am experiencing in Internet Explorer is that the readyState is turned to "interactive" before the element "toggled" even exists in the DOM. When the page is paused and the alert is called the document is still completely blank. I am pretty sure this is a bug, since it works fine in IE 11. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't you be checking `complete`?

Comment: Isn't complete the same as onload? I want to fire the event before the images / frames are loaded.

Comment: Why don't you use `document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("toggled").innerHTML = "ready";
      alert("Stop!");

}, false );`?

Comment: This is not supported in IE.

Comment: Since IE9+ it is : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ie/hh869434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
And that is what is used internally by jQuery 2.x